# 1st tab opens url in webview successfully but 2nd tab opens url in browser

Tags: android

I have this application with two tabs. When I access the layout, the first tab open successfully with a webpage loaded on a webview as the content of the tab. But when I try to access the second tab, it doesn't show the webview as the content; thus it directs to a browser to open the webpage. I have the same code for both classes which is accessed by my intent in the main activity. Here's what I've got:

TabbedActivity.java

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TabHost host=getTabHost();

    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("g")
    .setIndicator("Google")
    .setContent(new Intent(this, WebActivity2.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("y")
    .setIndicator("Yahoo")
    .setContent(new Intent(this, WebActivity3.class)));
    }
}
```

Here are the two classes I used as intent:

WebActivity2.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public class WebActivity2 extends Activity {
        WebView browser;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);

            WebView browser = new WebView(this);
            setContentView(browser);
            browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

WebActivity3.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")               
    public class WebActivity3 extends Activity {    
        WebView browser;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);

            WebView browser = new WebView(this);
            setContentView(browser);
            browser.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/ama.manilacampus");
        }
    }
```

I don't think the error's in my xml layout bacause it works well in the first tab. What could be this cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loading the facebook link, the webview is redirected. Because of the redirection, by default your webview will start browser activity. You can change that behavior by having the following code:

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    //to avoid browser prompting for actions when clicking on URLs
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);  
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely that your page is redirecting. See this related question to stop the `WebView` from opening the browser app. You need to implement a `WebViewClient` and return `true` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.